# Posting questions about playing dvds on linux okay legally?

Tags: discussion

I would like to post a question about how to get the Hobbit 2 to play on linux. I encountered some encryption problem. Is it okay to post a question on how to get around this encryption problem. I bought the dvd legally, but I am starting to question it is even legal to watch it on linux.

Comment: [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/138969/why-watching-dvds-on-linux-is-illegal-in-the-usa/) is a good article about it. I think asking a question about it is fine (people ask about downloading youtube videos all the time), but it's interesting that is, apparently, isn't exactly legal.

Answer (score 5):

We always should assume you are asking in good faith. This is an excerpt of the [most referenced post when dealing with DRM](https://meta.superuser.com/a/2215/235569):

> #### Unless it is a clear call for warez, discussion of DRM should be given the benefit of the doubt.
>
> Per Joel:
>
> > I would hate for us to censor legitimate, technical discussion just because what we're talking about happens to be illegal in some jurisdictions. We should have the same standards as universities: we should defend people's rights to free speech.
> >
> > I think it's VERY MUCH DEBATABLE whether breaking DRM for the purpose of making backups is even illegal. It would be unhealthy if our diamond mods were running around being as strict as the Disney Corporation Inc. on DRM. It is hard to argue that there's anything even remotely socially unacceptable about breaking DRM for the purpose of backing up something you legitimately own.
> >
> > And we're not even doing it, we're just *talking* about it.
>
> Therefore, unless the post looks egregiously illegal, assume it is being asked in good faith about removing DRM on things you own, for your own fair use.